# Openshift: how to install python modules from private repository?

Tags: python, git, ssh, openshift

I would like to be able to install python packages to openshift, but those packages live in my private repositories, on bitbucket.

How can I create a SSH key for Openshift, and how do I make Openshift use it when installing packages? (after adding the corresponding public key to bitbucket as a Deploy Key)

What I've tried:

I used `ssh-keygen` to create a key on `~/.openshift_ssh/`. It was created, but I'm not sure it is being used.

I also tried adding the publick key on `<jenkins_dir>/app-root/data/.ssh/jenkins_id_rsa.pub`, but the result is always the same. On the jenkins console output of the buildjob:

```
Doing git clone from ssh://git@bitbucket.org/jpimentel/zed.git to /tmp/easy_install-FpEKam/zed.git
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

So, at this time OpenShift does not offer a simple mechanism to do this. I would urge developers to look at https://gondor.io/support/dependencies/ for an effective solution to the problem.

That said, I was finally able to find an acceptable (at least, for me) workaround that works on both scalable and non scalable apps, with the following procedure:

1. create a deploy/ directory in the repository
2. put a copy of your private deploy key in said directory
3. create a bash script deploy/wrapper.sh that will run ssh with the provided key:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/deploy/id_deploy $@
   ```

   note the option passed to disable host key check; cloning will fail without it.
4. install dependencies in the build hook (`.openshift/action_hooks/build`). In my case I added something like

   ```
   echo "Cloning private repo..."
   source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate
   GIT_SSH=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/deploy/wrapper.sh pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/team/reponame.git#egg=reponame
   ```
5. commit everything and push it to openshift.
6. profit!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy your custom python modules then recommended way is to create a libs directory in the application source code root and push them to your application git repository. OpenShift will automatically pick your modules.

Comment: Frankly, this is not a viable option, especially if you have a largish repo to add (in my case, mainly static files for django, but I guess it can happens with all kinds of cartridges).
FTR, I raised a support case, hoping some workaround could be found before a proper solution is implemented.

Comment: @giallu could you share the results of the support case, if any, when they come?

Comment: Done, see my own answer.

Comment: @jpimentel did you like my answer? if so feel free to upvote :)