# Openshift SSH error cloning submodules from private repo

Tags: git, openshift

I know this was asked before but I couldn't find a solution that didn't involve making the repository public and/or using https with passwords in urls (instead of ssh with keys).

My problem is basically the same than described there: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/gitssh-in-bashprofile-not-working-for-git-push-and-causes-error-cloning-submodules

Long story short there is one submodule and one main app both are stored in private git repositories on github. On openshift the deploy push fails when the instance try to update the submodule because of SSH authentication issues.

Following the above thread recommendation I tried setting up a wrapper for git, with keys and know_host files the app-root data directory and set a GIT_SSH environment variable (using .bash_profile, rhc set-env, pre_build hook or Steven Merrill GIT SSH helper cartridge). It works fine when you ssh in the machine, but it doesn't when doing the deploy push as if the GIT_SSH is using the default one not the newly set one.

My questions:

1. Any way I get set the GIT_SSH to be used at all time not just when I SSH in the machine?
2. Any way I can disable the git submodule update --init --recursive so that I can launch it via script later?
3. Why are SSH public keys non visible and known_hosts not writeable in Openshift?

Thanks for you help!

EDIT:
Same when I SSH in the machine and do a "gear deploy HEAD", /var/lib/openshift//.ssh/known_hosts is used instead of /var/lib/openshift//app-root/data/.ssh/known_hosts

Answer (score 0):

My guess on your questions:

1. I don't think so: that would require setting the variable in the bash profile, but that's not available for edit. I tried with the `rhc evn set` command but [it did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335225/environment-variable-not-expanding-in-openshift)
2. not one that I know of
3. I think this is for security reasons. Users can only write to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

However, back to your source issue, I think you can use the same method I used in [Openshift: how to install python modules from private repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650667/openshift-how-to-install-python-modules-from-private-repository/26492161#26492161).

The solution I found is not optimal, but at least I do not need to use login/password pairs to access my private repos.