# Openshift 2.1 cannot set OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION using action hooks

Tags: python, django, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

I am trying to deploy a Django app on openshift (`python3.3`, `django1.7`, Openshift 2.1).

I need to set the `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` to point to an alternative `wsgi.py` location.

I have tried using the `pre_build` script to set the variable, using the following commands:

```
export OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION="$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"geartest4/wsgi.py
echo "-------> $OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION"
```

I can see during the `git push` that the `pre_build` script sets the variable correctly. The `echo` shows the correct path as expected. However `wsgi.py` does not launch and I get:

> CLIENT_ERROR: WSGI application was not found

When I immediately `ssh` into the gear and check the environment variable I see that `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION=""` is not set.

If I set the variable manually from my workstation using `rhc set-env OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION=/var/lib/openshift/gear_name/bla/bla` then the variable sticks, the wsgi server launches, and the app works fine.

The problem is that I don't want to use `rhc set-env` because that means I have to hardwire the gear name in the path. This becomes a problem when I want to do scaling with multiple gears.

Anyone have any ideas on how to set the variable and make stick?

Comment: There is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26335225/3246440), maybe it gives you another idea...

Answer (score 1):

The environment variable `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` can be set to a relative path like this:

```
rhc env set OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION=wsgi/wsgi.py
```

The openshift cartridge [openshift-django17 by jfmatth](https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17) uses this approach, too.